# images in grid change in specified time interval using jquery or other javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to develop an image grid that changes some images in random at specified intervals using jquery or any other javascript means. Please be noted that I do not need all the images to change at the same time. One group of an image can change in different time interval compared to others.

The images are positioned absolute to the parent div so that it one can fadeIn while the other fades out until it reaches the last stage.

I am completely stuck without any idea on how to achieve this. Could anyone help me with this? Following is my code

```js
(function(){
 let first = $('.column1 img:gt(0)');
  first.hide();
  let images = $('.column1').find('img');
  
  setInterval(function(){
    let current = $('.column1 img:visible');
    let next = current.next().length ? current.next():$('.column1 img:eq(0)');
    current.fadeOut(300);
    next.fadeIn(300);
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
#main__slider{
  width:40rem;
  height:25rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr)
}

.column1{
  border:1px solid;
  position:relative;
}

img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main__slider">
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://www.arup.com/-/media/arup/images/perspectives/themes/cities/cities-alive/cities-alive-header.jpg?h=1125&la=en&w=2000&hash=415B3F648DFB5F1822DD43328B988A2C78318E7F" alt="">
    <img src="https://livability.com/sites/default/files/Great%20Cities%20for%20Filmmakers.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/styles/large_article_preview/public/Common-dog-behaviors-explained.jpg?itok=FSzwbBoi" alt="">
    <img src="https://d17fnq9dkz9hgj.cloudfront.net/uploads/2018/03/Pomeranian_01.jpeg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--vHt6tbFa--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/xjmx1csashjww8j8jwyh.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://www.drdavidludwig.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/1-RIS_6IbCLYv1X3bzYW1lmA.jpeg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://www.railengineer.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/AT300_HULL-TRAINS_with-logo.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://www.virginexperiencedays.co.uk/content/img/product/large/steam-train-trip-17104839.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://www.healthline.com/hlcmsresource/images/topic_centers/977-When_do_girls_stop_growing-732x549-thumbnail.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://images.askmen.com/1080x540/2018/09/06-125712-how_to_talk_to_girls_on_tinder.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://www.familyeducation.com/sites/default/files/inline-images/baby%20girl%20names%20image.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn2.momjunction.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Learning-Activities.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/33/Team_Korea_Rio_2016_06.jpg/1200px-Team_Korea_Rio_2016_06.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://expo.advance.net/img/9c4d2bc2c7/width960/30gallery_state_indiv_gym_.jpeg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://cdn4.sportngin.com/attachments/call_to_action/9127/0843/_7006687_large.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/4pOVrNf6Ezmge6_VKHgYmAyCNoU=/0x0:3642x2712/1200x800/filters:focal(1275x341:1857x923)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/54106607/usa_today_9864342.0.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://livability.com/sites/default/files/Great%20Cities%20for%20Filmmakers.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/59bafdf204afdc5248726f5c/master/w_2400,c_limit/BMW-TA.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a kind of loop like below and also consider `random()` to have different timing for the fade function:

```js
$('.column1 img:eq(0)').each(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});

setInterval(function() {
  $('.column1 img:visible').each(function() {
    let next = $(this).next().length ? $(this).next() : $(this).parent().find('img:eq(0)');
    var t = Math.random()*2000;
    $(this).delay(t).fadeOut(500);
    next.delay(t).fadeIn(500);
  });
}, 3000);
```

```css
#main__slider {
  width: 40rem;
  height: 25rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr)
}

.column1 {
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main__slider">
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://www.arup.com/-/media/arup/images/perspectives/themes/cities/cities-alive/cities-alive-header.jpg?h=1125&la=en&w=2000&hash=415B3F648DFB5F1822DD43328B988A2C78318E7F" alt="">
    <img src="https://livability.com/sites/default/files/Great%20Cities%20for%20Filmmakers.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/styles/large_article_preview/public/Common-dog-behaviors-explained.jpg?itok=FSzwbBoi" alt="">
    <img src="https://d17fnq9dkz9hgj.cloudfront.net/uploads/2018/03/Pomeranian_01.jpeg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--vHt6tbFa--/c_scale,f_auto,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/xjmx1csashjww8j8jwyh.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://www.drdavidludwig.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/1-RIS_6IbCLYv1X3bzYW1lmA.jpeg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://www.railengineer.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/AT300_HULL-TRAINS_with-logo.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://www.virginexperiencedays.co.uk/content/img/product/large/steam-train-trip-17104839.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://www.healthline.com/hlcmsresource/images/topic_centers/977-When_do_girls_stop_growing-732x549-thumbnail.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://images.askmen.com/1080x540/2018/09/06-125712-how_to_talk_to_girls_on_tinder.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://www.familyeducation.com/sites/default/files/inline-images/baby%20girl%20names%20image.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn2.momjunction.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Learning-Activities.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/33/Team_Korea_Rio_2016_06.jpg/1200px-Team_Korea_Rio_2016_06.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://expo.advance.net/img/9c4d2bc2c7/width960/30gallery_state_indiv_gym_.jpeg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://cdn4.sportngin.com/attachments/call_to_action/9127/0843/_7006687_large.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/4pOVrNf6Ezmge6_VKHgYmAyCNoU=/0x0:3642x2712/1200x800/filters:focal(1275x341:1857x923)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/54106607/usa_today_9864342.0.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column1">
    <img src="https://livability.com/sites/default/files/Great%20Cities%20for%20Filmmakers.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/59bafdf204afdc5248726f5c/master/w_2400,c_limit/BMW-TA.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Afif, Thanks for your comments. It certainly changes to the next image. However, did you notice that I was trying to achieve something different? In this grid, one group of images will change at the 3rd second (let's say), then the next group of images will change in the 6th second. Your code, however, only changes the duration or fadeIn effect. In effect, the images changes at the same time, however, some has delayed fadeIn and fadeOut compared to others.

Comment: @jeff check the update, you may consider delay() in this case

Comment: Hi Afif. Thanks again for coming back. Could you please visit this link and scroll down to the bottom to see a grid that changes. This is what I am trying to achieve. http://www.playup.com.ar/. Could you please help me with that? Thanks

Comment: @jeff you want the rotation effect?

Comment: @afif. No I dont want rotation. As you will see a group of it changes in a time and then it takes a pause and then the next group changes.

Comment: In your code, there is certainly the image changes in different time intervals from the delay effect. However, one image change at one time and then wait for sometime and 3 or 4 images change at the next time. It seems like there is no control over the change in image sequence.

Comment: @jeff I simply made the basic idea that you can easily adjust, you can for example have two different group by changing the class name and apply a logic to each one. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/q9xL750n/ .. again it's not a perfect one, it's to give you an idea how you can handle this.

Comment: @afif. Right you said. It looks a little messy for me. I am sure. There must be some efficient way of achieving this. It is just a matter of trying out right? Anyway, I consider that this is the best outcome of this question and accept as the best answer. BTW.

Comment: @jeff yes simply try out different values and different interval .. you can also split more the images, etc ... and in case you are still not close to what you want you can ask another question again.

Comment: Sure. I will ask another question and request you to put your suggestions.

Comment: Hi. I posted a different question with the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54630709/grid-image-with-separate-time-intervals-for-changing-the-grid-items. Could you please check